# PHP OOP - return arrays into class(?)

Tags: php, arrays, oop, refactoring

I'm trying to use OOP ways.  I have bunch of methods that return same format of array.  I want to guarantee that user of this class knows what will be returned.  How would I go about doing that?  Please forgive me as I'm not sure of correct terminologies to describe my problem.

```
class myModel {
    public function getArray1(){
       $data = array();
       $id = array();
       ....
       return array('data'=>$data, 'id'=>$id); <== HOW TO GUARANTEE RETURN FORMAT
    };
    public function getArray2(){
       $data = array();
       $id = array();
       ....
       return array('data'=>$data, 'id'=>$id); <== HOW TO GUARANTEE RETURN FORMAT
    };
    public function getArray3(){
       $data = array();
       $id = array();
       ....
       return array('data'=>$data, 'id'=>$id); <== HOW TO GUARANTEE RETURN FORMAT
    };
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "factor it out" ?

Comment: I'm thinking maybe return array needs to be in a class so that it can guarantee array elements will be returned(?)  This way user of this "myModel" class doesn't have to know the name of the key of returned array.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Creating classes to store data in these circumstances are called DTO (Data Transfer Objects), or simply models. They are excellent practices if you want to ensure interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to define additional class for returning value:

```
class returnArray {
     $data = array();
     $id = array();

     function construct($data,$id) {
         $this->data = $data;
         $this->id = $id;
     }
}

//...

public function getArray1(){
   $data = array();
   $id = array();
   ....
   return new returnArray('data'=>$data, 'id'=>$id);
};
```

Then You can add accessors to the `returnArray` class or leave it as public if You want or even implement `__toString()` if necessary.